# Using struct Aliasname* for a function return type in C language

Tags: c, function

I am new to the C language! please forgive me if my question is easy or something. And also, I appreciate an easy explanation for my question, thank you so much.

I was reading about the list in C language and based on this sample code they are trying to create a list function:

```
typedef struct list{int data; struct list *next;} list;


list* creat_list(int d){
    list* head = malloc(sizeof(list));
    head ->data = d;
    head ->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

the way function works is straightforward for me, but I can't understand why they used `list*` as the function return type and what does it mean at all?
As I learned so far, `list*` means a pointer to the `struct list`, but, What does it mean to use a pointer from struct for function return type? and how can I know when should I use that?

if the rest of the code is important, I write it below

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"

typedef struct list{int data; struct list *next;} list;

int is_empty(const list *l){ return (l == NULL);}

list* creat_list(int d){
    list* head = malloc(sizeof(list));
    head ->data = d;
    head ->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

list* add_to_front(int d, list* h){
    list* head = creat_list(d);
    head ->next;
    return head;
}

list* array_to_list(int d[], int size){
    list* head = creat_list(d[0]);
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < size ; i++){
        head = add_to_front(d[i], head);
    }
    return head;
}

void print_list(list *h, char *title){
    printf("%s\n", title);
    while(h != NULL){ //checker!
        printf("%d :", h->data);
        h = h ->next;
    }
}

int main(){

    list list_of_int;
    list* head = NULL;
    int data[6]= {2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9};

    head = array_to_list(data, 6);
    print_list(head, "multiple elements list");
    printf("\n\n");



    //  Commented code is for single element list
    /*
    head = malloc(sizeof(list));
    printf("sizeof(list) = %lu\n", sizeof(list)); //long long ??
    head -> data = 5;
    head -> next = NULL;
    print_list(head, "single element list");
    printf("\n\n");

     */


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: _"they are trying to create a list function:_" : Who are _"they"_?  They are "trying" but  failing.  The semantics of `add_to_front` are do not do what its name suggests and the `h` argument is unused.  Also a "list" is a data structure not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`creat_list()` allocates memory for the list head (the first item on the list), and returns a pointer to that list so that it can be passed to other functions that operate on the list.  So in use you might have:

```
List* mylist = creat_list( 1 ) ;

add_to_front( 2, mylist ) ;
add_to_front( 3, mylist ) ;    
add_to_front( 10, mylist ) ;
```

Here `mylist` is passed to `add_to_front` so it knows which list it it adding to.  It allows you to have multiple lists:

```
List* Alist = creat_list( 1 ) ;
List* Blist = creat_list( 2 ) ;

add_to_front( 2, Alist ) ;
add_to_front( 3, Blist ) ;
```

---

Note the above makes sense only if `add_to_front()` has the semantics implied by its name.  The function presented in your question does not do that.  Adding to the *front* of a singly linked list is not straightforward, it is clearly designed only for appending to the *end*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great and clear answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not correct. `add_to_front` does not add something to the given list, it creates a _new_ list. So a call to `add_to_front` should never ignore the result. The proper way to call it is `mylist = add_to_front(456, mylist)`. Otherwise `mylist` never changes and the newly added element is instantly unreachable and thus a memory leak.

Comment: @koder : That comment applies to the OP's question.  Clearly it is a semantic error in his code.  I may address it shortly in this answer, but the question was not "_why does this code not work?_", but _only_ about the semantics of the pointer argument.

Comment: @Clifford if you address your explanations here, I would appreciate it, Thank you so much, this code is a sample code from the Coursera course for C programming.

Comment: @BabakAbdolahzade There is more than one such course in Coursera, and you have to enroll to see the material. Does the course not provide student support?  Either way, it is probably better to post a new question if you have other problems with the course material.  SO is a Q&A not a conversation.